# Dynamic assigning of regex pattern

Tags: asp.net, regex

Below Code works fine, If i'm hardcoding pattern in code, if i fetch this pattern from database then it doesnt work. Can anyone advise what im doing wrong

```
//This line works                    
string regularExpressionPattern =  @"\[(.*?)\]";;

//But this line when im fetching this from database as i have stored the pattern in it, it doesnt work. I'm assigning it the same value as above but this time from database
   string regularExpressionPattern = regExPattern.ToString();

                    string inputText = p.Text.ToString();
                    Regex re = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern);
                    foreach (Match m in re.Matches(inputText))
                    {
                        Response.Write("Match Found");
                    }
```

Comment: Probably you get `regularExpressionPattern` assigned with `[(.*?)]` and it matches only a single char, `(`, `.`, `*`, `?` or `)`. Check if you get the right value from DB.

Comment: Are you sure the backslashes are present in the DB at all?

Comment: I was saying this in database - @"\[(.*?)\]" and it didnt worked

Comment: but when i did this - [(.*?)\] - Saving just this... i removed @ and quotes then it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored the pattern as a string then maybe you need make it back to correct pattern style. it depends on how you stored that pattern in db.

```
    function getRegFromString(string){
    var a = string.split("/");
    modifiers= a.pop(); a.shift();
    pattern = a.join("/");
    return new RegExp(pattern, modifiers);
    }
    getRegFromString(regExPattern);
```

take a look here for more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/toString